# jQuery undefined returned from json file

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to get a array from a json but when I try to get that data it returns 'undefined'

Here's where I'm trying to get the data:

```
$.getJSON('saveGames/userID' + userID + '_SAVEALPHA.json', function(data) {
    console.log("Got data from saveJSON: " + data);
    var testVar = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(testVar);
    playersPokemon = testVar.pokemon;
    console.log(testVar.pokemon);
    console.log("Players Pokemon: " + playersPokemon);
});
```

The json file (generated by PHP)

```
"[{\"userID\":\"1\",\"saveName\":\"h\",\"pokemon\":[\"Pikachu\",\"Charmander\"]}]"
```

I have used a json validator to check this file and it was OK. I am trying to access this json file with jQuery (in case you didn't know).

Comment: that looks like a string, not JSON

Comment: In the callback you are logging `data`, `testVar`, and `testVar.pokemon`. What are their values?

Comment: @You JSON **is** a string.

Comment: @Barmar - that's apples to oranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string is an Array of an Object: `[{...}]`, the `pokemon` property is in the Object not the Array so to access it you need `testVar[0].pokemon`

Or you can remove the brackets from the JSON file if that's possible:

`"{\"userID\":\"1\",\"saveName\":\"h\",\"pokemon\":[\"Pikachu\",\"Charmander\"]}"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `jQuery.parseJSON(data)`. When you use `$.getJSON()`, jQuery automatically parses it -- that's the difference between `$.get()` and `$.getJSON()`.