# jQuery get an Array from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I need to get an array from a json file and I have no idea how to do it.

Here's the code I want to get the array from:

```
$.getJSON('saveGames/userID' + userID + '_SAVEALPHA.json', function(data) {
    console.log("Save data from: userID" + userID + "_SAVEALPHA.json: " + data);
    var testVar = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    var pokemonAryTest = testVar[0].pokemon;
    pokemonAry = [pokemonAryTest];
    console.log("loaded players Pokemon: " + pokemonAry);
    console.log(pokemonAry[0])
});
```

I have tried to change the index of `pokemonAry` to 1 and it returns undefined. And when I keep the index the same, it returns `["Pikachu, Charmander"]` so I think its acting like as if it's a string.

Here's the .json:

```
"[{\"userID\":\"1\",\"saveName\":\"g\",\"pokemon\":[\"Pikachu, Charmander\"]}]"
```

Comment: You defined `pokemonAry` as an array of one item.  Why do you expect it to have a second item?

Comment: If Pikacu and Charmander are supposed to be separate array items then you need the JSON to be `[\"Pikachu\", \"Charmander\"]`. Also, your `pokemonAryTest` variable should *already* be an array, it doesn't make sense to do `pokemonAry = [pokemonAryTest]`.

Comment: Did you figure this issue out? nnnnnn is correct - the array in your post contains a single string literal, but if you expect it to have two separate strings then they need to be delimited properly (i.e. the comma outside of the quotes). See [this plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MNQ7eKzDreY7GPtQsvWY?p=info) for an illustration and feel free to fork it with a better sample of your data.

Comment: Actually, after reading [your other (nearly identical) post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39563263/1575353), I see more of the sample data. See [this forked plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QI2pmz8DIYXhVhdX4KMa?p=preview) ...

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `getJSON()` method no need to parse `JSON` data, jQuery take care of it. :)

```
$.getJSON('saveGames/userID' + userID + '_SAVEALPHA.json', function(data) {
    console.log("Save data from: userID" + userID + "_SAVEALPHA.json: " + data);
    var pokemonAry = data[0].pokemon;
    console.log("loaded players Pokemon: " + pokemonAry);
    console.log(pokemonAry[0])
});
```

Comment: Well now I get this error: loaded players Pokemon: undefined
game.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined If you don't know what I'm doing I'm setting a variable to the pokemon array in the json that I posted above